# java variable declaration

Tags: java

what the below code line does in java.

```
private static final String PERMISSIONS_KEY = BaseActionStepsHandler.class.getName() + ".USER.ROLES";
```

Note:

`BaseActionStepsHandler` is java class,and it is extended in another java class
       `InvConfirmActionStepsHandler` .
      The above code is declared in  `BaseActionStepsHandler.java` and it is
      called in `InvConfirmActionStepsHandler` class like below

```
private static final String PERMISSIONS_KEY = BaseActionStepsHandler.class.getName() + ".USER.ROLES";
```

what does it mean.??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This creates a constant that holds the fully qualified name of the `BaseActionStepsHandler` class concatenated with `.USER.ROLES`.

So, its value will be:

```
com.some.pkg.BaseActionStepsHandler.USER.ROLES
```

It uses the so called class-literal - `ClassName.class`, which is a [`Class`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object for the class in question.

Comment: can you explain the last line little more..
 
   It uses the so called class-literal - ClassName.class, which is a Class object for the class in question.

Comment: @Manu: see example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895241/what-is-class-descriptor